# Count frequency of element in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

With array A[m X n], a[i][j] in [0..255]
I intend split array into 2 or 4 parts. Count frequency of each part.
After combine.
Can you show me how to use OpenMP to implement this !

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Don't ask users to do work for you. Instead try to learn how OpenMP works and write some code. If you get some problems, find solutions or ask questions.

Comment: I split into n parts ( n threads). I use n arrays freq[n][256]. Each array count frequency in each thread. After combine n arrays. My laptop 2 cores/ 4 threads, with num_threads = 2, faster than using 1 thread, but if num_theads = 4, slower than using 2 threads. I post my question, hope that anyone show me other recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is hard to tell what is going wrong with your program.  You say that you're combining n arrays?  How do you do that?  If it is Fortran, then you might be using array reductions.  If it is C/C++, how are you combining the arrays (OpenMP for C/C++ does not support array reductions yet [except for user-defined reductions in OpenMP 4.0]).

Cheers,
        -michael

Comment: Don't use reduction. Ex use 4 threads : 4 arrays freq[4][256]. Combine, frequency[i] = freq[0][i] + freq[1][i] + freq[2][i] + freq[3][i]